# Integrar Alamofire en una libreria Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift2, swift, xcode

estoy realizando un componente en github integrado con cocoapods , la cosa es que quiero hacer uso de Alamofire dentro del componente y claro no he visto por ningún lado como hacer uso de una libreria como Alamofire dentro de otra propia libreria que sería el componente que estoy creando yo.
Alguna idea? He intentado de añadir los archivos de manera manual pero sin suerte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer no es integrar la `Alamofire` en tu librería sino que en las especificaciones del `Pod` indicar que `Alamofire` es una dependencia. De esta manera, cuando se instale tu librería, también lo hará `Alamofire`

En la web de [Cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/specs-and-specs-repo.html) encontrarás como añadir dependencias

Uno de los ejemplos de la web es este

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = 'libPusher'
  spec.version      = '1.3'
  spec.license      = 'MIT'
  spec.summary      = 'An Objective-C client for the Pusher.com service'
  spec.homepage     = 'https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher'
  spec.author       = 'Luke Redpath'
  spec.source       = { :git => 'git://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher.git', :tag => 'v1.3' }
  spec.source_files = 'Library/*'
  spec.requires_arc = true
  spec.dependency 'SocketRocket'
end
```

Si te fijas, la última línea indica una dependencia a `SocketRocket` lo que hará que se instale junto a la librería del ejemplo.

Comment: Hey gracias !! la verdad que tenía ya añadido ese parametro pero tenia una idea diferente acerca de eso y no le di a pod install de nuevo en el proyecto de ejemplo, aprovecho para preguntarte si hizistes uso de BD interna en una libreria que luego haga uso compartido con el proyecto en el cual la integras? en su dia lo intente y me daba conflicto con REALM . Gracias por tu tiempo!